# How to fix counter not showing correct value as well as resetting with new string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m6vxgg0m/15/

The console log shows the output.

I've been trying to get the number of occurrences of a string in an array using jQuery. The loop I'm using to check if the string value is present in each index of the array appears to be correct. I'm not sure why it isn't working correctly. I never get the correct counter value. If I keep the string in the text field and I keep hitting enter, the counter keeps increasing even though I set the counter back to 0 right inside the keyup event. If there are two occurrences of a string in the array, the counter should always display the value of 2. But it doesn't. Very frustrated.

JS:

```js
 $(function(){ keywordSearchFeature() });

 function keywordSearchFeature(){
   
   // Selector Variables
   var inputSel = $('#search-term');
   var noticeLblSel = $('.searchInstance');
   var contentSel = $('.RadGrid.RadGrid_Default.mydatagrid .rgMasterTable tr');

   // Functional Variables
   var keywordVal;
   var keywordValL; // keywordVal lowercase
   var keyCounter = 0; // counter
  var cellValues = []; // 
   var cellValuesL = []; // cellValues lowercase

   // Type keyword
   inputSel.on('keyup', function(e){
  
  // Reset Counter
  keyCounter = 0;
  
  // Keyword Value
  keywordVal = $(this).val();
  
  // Keyword Lowercase Value
  keywordValL = keywordVal.toLowerCase();
  
  // console.log(keywordValL);
  
  // Clear notice label when retyping
  noticeLblSel.text('');
  
  // Enter Key
  if (e.which == 13) {
    
    if(keywordValL != null && keywordValL != '' && keywordValL.length > 3){
   
   console.log('ENTER KEY CLICKED: Value entered is: ' + keywordValL);
   
   // Store content in arraykeyinstances[]
   contentSel.each(function(i,tr){
    var tdLines = $('td',tr).map(function(i,td){
    
    // Get each cell string, and trim whitespace
    var tdCellContent = $(td).text().trim();
    
    // console.log(tdCellContent);
    
    // Push each cell value to array
    cellValues.push(tdCellContent);
    cellValuesL.push(tdCellContent.toLowerCase());
     });
   });
   
   // console.log(cellValues);
   console.log(cellValuesL);
   
   for (var i = 0; i < cellValuesL.length; i++) {
     if (cellValuesL[i] == keywordValL) {
    keyCounter++;
     }
   }
   
   console.log(keyCounter);
   
   // Notice label text 
   if(keyCounter > 0) {
    noticeLblSel.text('Instance 1 of ' + keyCounter + ' found on this page.');
   } else {
    noticeLblSel.text('No instances for "' + keywordVal + '" found.');
   }
    } else {
   noticeLblSel.text('Please enter 4 or more characters.');
    }
  }
   });
   
   // Click Events
   //$(document).on('click','.btn-searchnext',function(){});
   //$(document).on('click','.btn-searchprev',function(){});

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formholder searchkeywordholder">
   <div class="form_inner">
    <div class="formrow form-col-1" tabindex="0">
     <div id="find-in-page">
      <div class="fielditem searchfielditem">
       <input type="text"
        id="search-term"
        placeholder="Type in the phrase to search and click Next..."
        title="Enter Search Phrase"
        class="text searchfield"
        aria-label="Search Keyword Field" />
       <button id="next"
        class="button bttn-clear btn-searchnext"
        title="Next"
        aria-label="Search Next Button">
        Next
       </button>
       <button id="prev"
        class="button bttn-find btn-searchprev"
        title="Previous"
        aria-label="Search Previous Button">
        Previous
       </button>
      </div>
      <label id="labelResult" class="searchInstance"></label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="RadGrid RadGrid_Default mydatagrid staticheaders nostripes" id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems" tabindex="0">
    <div class="rgDataDiv" id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_GridData">
     <table class="rgMasterTable rgClipCells rgClipCells" id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00">

      <tbody>
       <tr class="groupinghighlight" id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00__0">
        <td valign="middle">
         <div>
          
         </div>
        </td>
        <td>
         <div>
          <div>
           <div id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl04_divChildAssetStyle">
            Antenna B1
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </td>
        <td>
         Equipment and Materials
        </td>
        <td>
         C2 Equipment
        </td>
        <td>
         Antenna
        </td>
        <td>
         Basic
        </td>
        <td>
         B1
        </td>
        <td>
         <div class="rating_general rating_yellow" id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl04_divRating" title="Asset's Rate">
          0.36
         </div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
         <span class="aspNetDisabled"><input disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl04_checkboxOverride" name="ctl00$MainContent$customProjectAssets$gridItems$ctl00$ctl04$checkboxOverride" type="checkbox"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
         <span id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl04_spanAssetTag" title="Incident Response/Recovery">IRR</span>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
         <span id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl04_spanClassificationLevel" title="UNCLASSIFIED">U</span>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
         <input id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl04_checkboxDelete" name="ctl00$MainContent$customProjectAssets$gridItems$ctl00$ctl04$checkboxDelete" onclick="$.onCheckDeleteChange('0');" type="checkbox">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="groupinghighlight" id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00__1">
        <td valign="middle">
         <div>
          
         </div>
        </td>
        <td>
         <div>
          <div style="width: 200px; margin: 0 auto;">
           <div id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl05_divChildAssetStyle">
            Content 1
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </td>
        <td>
         This is content
        </td>
        <td>
         My text
        </td>
        <td>
         lorem ipsum dolor
        </td>
        <td>
         sit amet
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
         <div class="rating_general rating_orange" id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl05_divRating" title="Asset's Rate">
          0.56
         </div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
         <span class="aspNetDisabled"><input disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl05_checkboxOverride" name="ctl00$MainContent$customProjectAssets$gridItems$ctl00$ctl05$checkboxOverride" type="checkbox"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
         <span id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl05_spanAssetTag" title="No Asset Tag Assigned"></span>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
         <span id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl05_spanClassificationLevel" title="UNCLASSIFIED">U</span>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
         <input id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl05_checkboxDelete" name="ctl00$MainContent$customProjectAssets$gridItems$ctl00$ctl05$checkboxDelete" onclick="$.onCheckDeleteChange('1');" type="checkbox">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00__2">
        <td valign="middle">
         <div>
          
         </div>
        </td>
        <td>
         <div>
          <div style="width: 200px; margin: 0 auto;">
           <div class="iconGridSubordinateArrow" id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl06_divChildArrowImage" style="float: left; width: 17px;"></div>
           <div id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl06_divChildAssetStyle" style="float: left; width: 180px;">
            equivalent
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </td>
        <td>
         People
        </td>
        <td>
         Individuals
        </td>
        <td>
         lorem
        </td>
        <td>
         ipsum
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
         <div class="rating_general rating_yellow" id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl06_divRating" title="Asset's Rate">
          0.44
         </div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
         <span class="aspNetDisabled"><input disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl06_checkboxOverride" name="ctl00$MainContent$customProjectAssets$gridItems$ctl00$ctl06$checkboxOverride" type="checkbox"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
         <span id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl06_spanAssetTag" title="No Asset Tag Assigned"></span>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
         <span id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl06_spanClassificationLevel" title="UNCLASSIFIED">U</span>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
         <input id="ctl00_MainContent_customProjectAssets_gridItems_ctl00_ctl06_checkboxDelete" name="ctl00$MainContent$customProjectAssets$gridItems$ctl00$ctl06$checkboxDelete" onclick="$.onCheckDeleteChange('2');" type="checkbox">
        </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: For a question about a counter not counting correctly your sample HTML is a bit too elaborate. Can you reduce it to something like... one `<input>` and one `<div>`? That ought to be enough. Also, a lot of the JS code is probably unrelated. Throw out anything that has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the reason that your `keyCounter` increases each time you hit enter is because you do not reset `cellValuesL` to an empty array in your `keyup` event handler. This means that after the first time you hit enter, the `contentSel` table is parsed and 36 text values are pushed onto `cellValuesL`. The next time you hit enter, `contentSel` is parsed again and the same 36 values are again pushed onto `cellValuesL` so that `cellValuesL.length` is now 72. The same 36 values get pushed onto `cellValuesL` each time you hit the enter key.

One way you can fix this is by moving `var cellValuesL = [];` to inside the `keyup` event handler. However, a better solution is to move the code that builds the `cellValuesL` array (`contentSel.each`) to outside of the `keyup` event handler. As the text values in the table never change, it does not make sense to keep fetching the texts from the table and building a new array each time the user presses the enter key.

To your second point about having two occurrences of a string in your `cellValuesL` array, I think you must be confused about what your code is checking. Your code loops through each value in `cellValuesL` and for each element in that array that equals the lower-cased user input, `keyCounter` is incremented. In your example, no two elements in `cellValuesL` are equal, so it is not possible for the loop to ever produce more than one match. What I assume you must want to is to check whether each element in `cellValuesL` *contains* the lower-cased user input. If this is the desired behavior, you will need to update your conditional to the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cellValuesL.length; i++) {
    if (cellValuesL[i].indexOf(keywordValL) > -1) {
        keyCounter++;
    }
}
```

A more modern and elegant way of achieving the same thing as the code above would be to use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
keyCounter = cellValuesL.filter(val => val.indexOf(keywordValL) > -1).length;
```

Finally, I want to suggest that your JavaScript code can be cleaned-up quite a bit. Here is an example that doesn't use any ES6 language features:

```
$(function () {

    var inputSel = $('#search-term');
    var contentSel = $('.RadGrid.RadGrid_Default.mydatagrid .rgMasterTable tr');
    var noticeLblSel = $('.searchInstance');
    var cellValuesL = $('td', contentSel).map(function () {
        return $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase();
    }).get();

    inputSel.on('keyup', function (e) {
        noticeLblSel.text('');

        if (e.which !== 13) { return; }

        var keywordVal = $(this).val();
        var keywordValL = keywordVal.toLowerCase();

        if (!keywordValL || keywordValL.length <= 3) { 
            noticeLblSel.text('Please enter 4 or more characters.');
            return;
        }

        var keyCounter = cellValuesL.filter(function (val) {
            return val.indexOf(keywordValL) > -1;
        }).length;

        if (keyCounter > 0) {
            noticeLblSel.text('Instance 1 of ' + keyCounter + ' found on this page.');
        } else {
            noticeLblSel.text('No instances for "' + keywordVal + '" found.');
        }
    });

});
```

I have also created an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/qLp49csn/).